# AWS ECS EC2 doesn't get added to Cluster - Task cannot be run (Learner Lab)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs3tyVgiBQQ in order to run a Wordpress blog on ECS with an ECR image.
I pulled the official wordpress image from docker, ran, tagged and pushed it to the ECR.
Created the ECS Cluster - first thing I noticed here was that the EC2 that got created with it didn't show up in the Clusters ECS-Instances (I suppose that is the problem? but no clue as to why it doesn't show up because it does get created - I can see it in the EC2 dashboard)

Well the problem where I definitely can't continue on from is that I get the error message (~Task cannot be run) "No Container Instances were found in cluster", when I try to run the previously created task definition.

Help?

I am using the AWS Learner Lab - I don't know if this is relevant but one thing I know is I can't create IAM roles/users.

Iried doing everything again from step 1 - ran into the same problem again.
Tried doing it with a Windows machine instead of Linux - that one didn't even show up in the EC2 dashboard (didn't get created at all?).

Comment: Yes, the instance not joining the cluster is the problem.  Here's a troubleshooting guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-instance-unable-join-cluster/

Comment: @MarkB thanks for taking the time out of your day to try and help me.
I wasn't really able to make sense of the data the tool gave me, but I found my error and was able to solve it :)
In case anyone wants to know: the "first" subnet (that's what the tutorial said I should pick) wasn't the default one but some custom nonsense that got created while trying to solve an earlier assignment. So using the default one instead did the trick. :)